# Check for class of columns in dataframe

Tags: r

I have a toy dataframe `df` with 2 columns of class `integer` and `factor`. However, when I tried to check whether a column is factor, I got incorrect result as follows

```
num <- c(1:5)
fac <- factor(letters[1:5])
df <- data.frame(num, fac)
df
# num fac
1   1   a
2   2   b
3   3   c
4   4   d
5   5   e
cols <- colnames(df)    
for (col in cols) {
  print(col)
  print(is.factor(df$col))
}
[1] "num"
[1] FALSE
[1] "fac"
[1] FALSE
```

What I did wrong. How can I check whether a column in a dataframe is factor or binary?

Comment: The error was in passing a character value to the ‘$’ function. Should have been `is.factor(df[[col]])’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `df$col` refers to a column named "col" in the data frame `df`. That column doesn't exist - you'd think that `is.factor` might return an error in that case, but it returns FALSE instead.

You could refer to the column a different way:

```
for(col in cols) {
  print(col)
  print(is.factor(df1[, col]))
}

[1] "num"
[1] FALSE
[1] "fac"
[1] TRUE
```

But most people would use `str` to summarise column types:

```
str(df)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ num: int  1 2 3 4 5
 $ fac: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5
```

Or you could use `sapply` instead of a loop:

```
sapply(df, is.factor)
  num   fac 
FALSE  TRUE 

sapply(df1, class, USE.NAMES = TRUE)
      num       fac 
"integer"  "factor"
```